# Link a property of a UserControl with a property of a BO

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have a WPF `MyUserControl`.

That MyUserControl contains a private _MyBusinessObject.

Say, I have a BO property of `MyBusinessObject` named `Location`(Windows.Point).

I need to "link" the "Location" of _MyBusinessObject to the `Margin` (Windows.Thickness) of MyUserControl.
Say, I link Left=X and Top=Y.

Can I etablish a binding or something like this between the UserControl and the internal BO property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `MyBusinessObject` implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) you can easily create a [binding in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx). You will of course have to convert from `Point` to `Thickness`by means of a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).